# How to rearrange the values in list based on the values in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list as follows:

```
PastValues = [76978.359, 71079.933, 75580.227]
```

I did:

```
PastValues2 = PastValues + [-value for value in PastValues]
```

to create the negative values of the values in the `PastValues` and to join them with the values in the `PastValues` and it gave me the following list `PastValues2`:

```
[76978.359, 71079.933, 75580.227, -76978.359, -71079.933, -75580.227]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to rearrange the values in the `PastValues2` to be of the same order as in `PastValues`.

**Desired output:**

```
PastValues2 = [-76978.359, 76978.359, -71079.933, 71079.933, -75580.227, 75580.227]
```

Since in the `PastValues` list `76978.359` was the first element, I want the first 2 elements in the `PastValues2` to be the negative and the positive values of it, respectively. Similarly for the other elements in the `PastValues` list. The negative values should come before the positive values

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
[e for i in PastValues for e in [-i, i]]

# [-76978.359, 76978.359, -71079.933, 71079.933, -75580.227, 75580.227]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list and form negative and positive in each iteration. Finally flatten the obtained result to match with desired output:

```
from itertools import chain

PastValues = [76978.359, 71079.933, 75580.227]

result = list(chain.from_iterable(([-x, x] for x in PastValues)))
# [-76978.359, 76978.359, -71079.933, 71079.933, -75580.227, 75580.227]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy based approach using broadcast multiplication:

```
(np.array(PastValues)*np.array([-1,1])[:,None]).ravel('F')

array([-76978.359,  76978.359, -71079.933,  71079.933, -75580.227,
        75580.227])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through double for cycle:

```py
PastValues = [76978.359, 71079.933, 75580.227]

PastValues2 = [value*sign for value in PastValues for sign in [-1,1]]

# [-76978.359, 76978.359, -71079.933, 71079.933, -75580.227, 75580.227]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator.neg` and `itertools.chain`. this will be more efficient than comprehensions, especially nested ones!

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import neg

PastValues = [76978.359, 71079.933, 75580.227]

PastValues2 = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(map(neg, PastValues), PastValues)))
```